# querying oracle table based on cumulative amount based of fiscal year and fiscal period

Tags: sql, oracle

Before I explain what I'm trying to accomplish let me begin by showing you the data that I'm working with. This is part of a much larger table, so this is simply a subset of that data that I believe would best represent the question that I'm trying to answer.
Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE "MIGUEL83"."CUM_LEDGER" 
   ( "FIELD_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
  "ACCOUNT_CODE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
  "TRANASCTION_AMOUNT" NUMBER, 
  "GRANT_CODE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
  "FISCAL_PERIOD" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
  "FISCAL_YEAR" NUMBER(20,0)
   )



 Insert for table.
    Insert into CUM_LEDGER (FIELD_NAME,ACCOUNT_CODE,TRANASCTION_AMOUNT,GRANT_CODE,FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR) values ('YTD','2010',11019.9,'202118','12',2006);
    Insert into CUM_LEDGER (FIELD_NAME,ACCOUNT_CODE,TRANASCTION_AMOUNT,GRANT_CODE,FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR) values ('YTD','2010',5084.08,'202118','10',2007);
    Insert into CUM_LEDGER (FIELD_NAME,ACCOUNT_CODE,TRANASCTION_AMOUNT,GRANT_CODE,FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR) values ('YTD','2010',1105.39,'202118','11',2007);
    Insert into CUM_LEDGER (FIELD_NAME,ACCOUNT_CODE,TRANASCTION_AMOUNT,GRANT_CODE,FISCAL_PERIOD,FISCAL_YEAR) values ('YTD','2010',0,'202118','12',2007);
```

what I would like to do is basically write a query that would sum all amounts up until the fiscal year and period that I decided. So in other words if  I set my where clause to say something like "where my fiscal_period = '10' and my fiscal_year = '2007' " . I would like to include the items previous to that fiscal year and period  as well so in this case there is one amount for 11019.9 in fiscal_year 2006 for fiscal period 12 that i should be including since that transaction happened before the fiscal year and period for wish I'm querying for.

expected results should look like 
[image]

here is my lousy attempt at writing this SQL which I know wont work and it needs help.

```
SELECT
  FIELD_NAME,
  ACCOUNT_CODE,
  sum(TRANASCTION_AMOUNT),
  GRANT_CODE,
  FISCAL_PERIOD,
  FISCAL_YEAR
FROM MIGUEL83.CUM_LEDGER 
WHERE FISCAL_PERIOD = '10'
AND FISCAL_YEAR = '2007'
group by 
 FIELD_NAME,
  ACCOUNT_CODE,
  GRANT_CODE,
  FISCAL_PERIOD,
  FISCAL_YEAR;
```

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer.

Comment: Is the previous fiscal period called "09" or "9"?

Comment: it is 09 at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT
    sum(TRANASCTION_AMOUNT)
FROM MIGUEL83.CUM_LEDGER 
WHERE (TO_NUMBER(FISCAL_PERIOD) <= 10 AND FISCAL_YEAR = 2007)
OR FISCAL_YEAR < 2007
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work I will test with the larger scale and if it checks out I will award you the response thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: It is pretty simple.  I think you tried to overcomplicated things with your solution.  Try to focus on what you need to achieve.